# Can I print out my Schengen Visa documents without color?

Tags: schengen, germany, schengen-visas

I cannot read from anywhere that says some specific documents need to be printed with color. I know that the passport copy is quite important but unfortunately I only have access to a monochrome printer. Can/Should I submit all my documents printed in black & white mode?

For detail: I'm applying for a German Schengen Visa from an Asian country.

Comment: If color copies are required, then they will state so explicitly. If the authenticity needs to be verified, then it is the text (and not the color) that is being verified. When a document has a specific background color, then the verification confirms that the original has that color.

Comment: And I'm pretty sure the automatic processing systems would convert it back to black and white anyways.

Answer (score 1):

I recently applied for the Schengen Visa at the German Consulate in Toronto. All of my papers were black and white. The guy at the consulate took a quick look to compare my original passport and the copy version, and **returned** the copy to me. So you will probably be fine, tho I can't speak for the German Consulate in other countries. I got approved in less than a week (applied on Tuesday, received my passport on the morning of next Tuesday)